# Lazy Load of Kendo UI Grid with scrollbar

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, lazy-loading

How do I make a kendo grid load virtually?

Suppose I have 10,000 records and I want to display only 30 records when the page loads, how do I lazy load additional an additional block of 30 records when a user scrolls down? Just like the Facebook wall.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [this demo here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/virtualization-remote-data.html) which describes how to set up the Kendo grid for virtualization with remote data, but in short you need to specify that the grid is to be virtualized on initialization.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({                
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    }
});
```